# nib files will not compiled into app if i choose ios device,but simulator is ok

Tags: ios, nib

it's weird that when i choose a simulator and compile,the my.app contains MainWindow.nib.but when i choose a ios device and compile ,the my.app doesn't contain the MainWindow.nib and result in errors.

error:
'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle  (loaded)' with name 'MainWindow''

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 reasons:

1. Your xib is not named "MainWindow.xib"
2. Your xib is not added in your project.
3. "MainWindow.nib" does not exist in the builded app.

If you there are not these problems. Check localization in xib.

Open xib in ifacebuilder and take a look at the right-menu in xcode. there is a section called "localization"

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before when the case of the actual file is different from what you're requesting. The Mac OS X file system is not case-sensitive, but the iOS file system is.